# How to create KDE tray notification in a C++ program?

Tags: c++, qt, system-tray, kde-plasma

I have a C++ program (that uses Qt), and I want to create a tray notification with a progress bar. I think Qt can show text notifications, but not progress bar - that's KDE-specific. I can't find any example of managing KDE tray notifications in C++. Any advice?

P. S. Here's what I mean:

[image]

Comment: Do you want something like a tooltip with a progressbar in it?

Comment: @Nejat: yep. Give me a sec, I'll add a screenshot from a native KDE app.

Comment: Maybe this is what I need. Not sure. Looks pretty hard to use: http://api.kde.org/4.0-api/kdelibs-apidocs/kdeui/html/classKNotification.html#_details

Answer (score 5):

I was wondering the same thing, and I spent some time investigating. Here are the results:

### Introduction

That progress bar is a special feature of kde that's not linked to libnotify at all. It is provided by a component called kuiserver, and it is meant to display progress of file transfert, though it can be used for other things.

There are two ways

### KJob

The first way is to talk to kuiserver in the KDE API, and it's by using [KUiServerJobTracker](http://api.kde.org/frameworks-api/frameworks5-apidocs/kjobwidgets/html/classKUiServerJobTracker.html) with a [KJob](http://api.kde.org/frameworks-api/frameworks5-apidocs/kcoreaddons/html/classKJob.html). I haven't tried myself, but I guess you should subclass KJob, and pass an instance of your subclass to KUiServerJobTracker.

### dbus

You can also talk directly to the kuiserver through dbus, which is what I tried. I used `qdbusviewer` to explore the API provided by kuiserver. I wanted to show an example of interaction with the command-line tool `qdbus`, but I couldn't get it to work. If you plan to do this, you probably should use 
the QDBus library.

What is interesting to us is the `/JobViewServer` path in the `org.kde.kuiserver` service. The method we want to call is `org.kde.JobViewServer.requestView`, which creates a new dbus path for this job, and returns it. For example, I just called `requestView` with dummy arguments, and got `ObjectPath: /JobViewServer/JobView_29` in return. In the meantime, a progress indicator has just started rotating in my tray:

I can now use the content of that path. Here, `qdbus` worked, so here is the list of the methods:

```
$ qdbus org.kde.kuiserver /JobViewServer/JobView_29
signal void org.kde.JobViewV2.cancelRequested()
method Q_NOREPLY void org.kde.JobViewV2.clearDescriptionField(uint number)
signal void org.kde.JobViewV2.resumeRequested()
method bool org.kde.JobViewV2.setDescriptionField(uint number, QString name, QString value)
method Q_NOREPLY void org.kde.JobViewV2.setDestUrl(QDBusVariant destUrl)
method Q_NOREPLY void org.kde.JobViewV2.setInfoMessage(QString message)
method Q_NOREPLY void org.kde.JobViewV2.setPercent(uint percent)
method Q_NOREPLY void org.kde.JobViewV2.setProcessedAmount(qulonglong amount, QString unit)
method Q_NOREPLY void org.kde.JobViewV2.setSpeed(qulonglong bytesPerSecond)
method Q_NOREPLY void org.kde.JobViewV2.setSuspended(bool suspended)
method Q_NOREPLY void org.kde.JobViewV2.setTotalAmount(qulonglong amount, QString unit)
signal void org.kde.JobViewV2.suspendRequested()
method Q_NOREPLY void org.kde.JobViewV2.terminate(QString errorMessage)
method QDBusVariant org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get(QString interface_name, QString property_name)
method QVariantMap org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.GetAll(QString interface_name)
method void org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Set(QString interface_name, QString property_name, QDBusVariant value)
method QString org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable.Introspect()
method QString org.freedesktop.DBus.Peer.GetMachineId()
method void org.freedesktop.DBus.Peer.Ping()
```

I'll let you guess and experiment to find what those do, but here is a small example:

```
# Give it a name, in case we open the tooltip
qdbus org.kde.kuiserver /JobViewServer/JobView_29 setInfoMessage "Example progress"
# Update the progress
qdbus org.kde.kuiserver /JobViewServer/JobView_29 setPercent 50
# End it
qdbus org.kde.kuiserver /JobViewServer/JobView_29 terminate "Some error message"
```

### Conclusion

You should have enough to create a progress bar in the tray with kde. I hope this'll be useful to you. Anyway, I had fun finding this out (including diving in some kde applications code to find out how the progress notification was done), and I'll probably write something that uses this.

Comment: FYI, I found out that qdbus does not work to create jobs as the job will be automatically deleted if the dbus client which created it quits (which qdbus does right away). I'm now using qtruby to script basically the same thing, but while keeping the connection open.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [QxtToolTip](http://libqxt.bitbucket.org/doc/0.6/qxttooltip.html) which is a class in [Qxt](http://dev.libqxt.org/libqxt/wiki/Home). It enabales you to show any arbitrary widget as a tooltip. So i think you can create your custom widget and show it using QxtToolTip in the proper position. You can use this static function:

```
void QxtToolTip::show ( const QPoint & pos, QWidget * tooltip, QWidget * parent = 0, const QRect & rect = QRect() )   [static]
```

It can be like:

```
#include <QxtToolTip>

MyCustomWidget widget;
QPoint myPosition(x,y);
QxtToolTip::show ( &myPosition, &widget, parent);
```

Comment: Interesting, didn't know about this library. But I want to look native, so I need to use some KDE and Gnome facilities on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

To get in the system tray you want to use KStatusNotifierItem and for the notifications you'll want to take a look at the KNotifications framework.

Comment: Can't find how to create / display a progress bar, though. Any tips?

Comment: Huh. My application crashes on startup once I link to `kdeui`.